# SQL*Loader-485: table <table name> may not be loaded using a subtype

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I try to load tables in a certain schema using SQL*Loader. but I receive the error:
**SQL***Loader-485: table  may not be loaded using a subtype

Can you help me please ?

**employee.ctl:**
OPTIONS (skip=1)
LOAD DATA
REPLACE
INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
 ( id, name, dept, salary )

---

**employee.txt**
100,Thomas,Sales,5000
200,Jason,Technology,5500
300,Mayla,Technology,7000
400,Nisha,Marketing,9500
500,Randy,Technology,6000
501,Ritu,Accounting,5400

**This is the commande:**
sqlldr userid="user/password@shemaRemote" control="...dir\employee.ctl" log="...dir\employee.log" bad="...dir\employee.bad" data="...dir\employee.txt"

Comment: Could you edit the question and post the EMPLOYEE table description?

Comment: Your salary data has a space in it. `5000 200`.  is that intentional or a data error?  If intentional, you'll need to allow for that in the control file.  if a data error, contact the data provider to fix it.  Don't compensate for bad data from a data provider, have them fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I found the solution from an oracle note. This is caused by a table called DUAL existng in schema that owns the table i want to load. SQL> select owner, object_name,object_type from dba_objects where object_name ='DUAL' ; normally the only allowed objects called DUAL in data directory are these: SYS and PUBLIC. If you see additional objects (that was my case) you should delete the additional objects that is responsible for this strange behabior.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for reporting back.